# How to find item selected from customContextMenuRequested() on QTreeView item?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have implemented contextual menus in QTreeView items with the following code

```
MyDerivedQTreeView->setModel(MyDerivedQAbstractItemModel);
MyDerivedQTreeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);  
connect(MyDerivedQTreeView,   
        SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)),   
        MyDerivedQAbstractItemModel(),   
        SLOT(contextualMenu(const QPoint &)));

void MyDerivedQAbstractItemModel::contextualMenu(const QPoint& point)
{
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu;
    menu->addAction(QString("Test Item"), this, SLOT(test_slot()));
    menu->exec(MyDerivedQTreeView->mapToGlobal(point));
}
```

MyDerivedQAbstractItemModel::contextualMenu() gets called and I can see the contextual menu.

Problem is contextual menu should be visible only if user right-clicks on an item and it should be customized as per the item selected.

How do I get whether/which item is selected from QPoint information? I am on Qt 4.5.3.

Comment: I have tried MyDerivedQAbstractItemModel::getItem(MyDerivedQTreeView->currentIndex()). It returns first item by default even if I don't right-click on an item. It always returns an item even if I click on any empty space in the QTreeView.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [indexAt()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) method of QTreeView to get the item where the click is made, before constructing your custom menu.

Comment: Thanks. This works.
Although getItem(MyDerivedQTreeView->indexAt(point)) returns a non-NULL item, I can query for properties set on the item to find if it is a valid item.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code will help you:

==> dialog.h <==

```
QStandardItemModel *model;
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;
QTreeView *treeView;
```

==> dialog.cpp <==

```
void    CImportTabWidget::createGUI() {
    ...
    proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
    proxyModel->setDynamicSortFilter(true);

    treeView = new QTreeView;
    treeView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    treeView->setRootIsDecorated(false);
    treeView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    treeView->setModel(proxyModel);

    model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 4);
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Comment"));
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Size"));
    model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Date"));

    fillTreeViewData();

    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
    ...
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void    CImportTabWidget::createMenus() {

    treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

    connect(treeView,
        SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)),
        this,
        SLOT(contextMenu(const QPoint &)));
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void    CImportTabWidget::contextMenu(const QPoint &widgetXY) {

    Q_UNUSED(widgetXY);

    QMenu menu(this);

    /* Условия для меню */
    deleteAct->setEnabled((!model->rowCount()) ? false : true );
    deleteAllAct->setEnabled((!model->rowCount()) ? false : true );

    /* Находим индекс */
    QModelIndex index = treeView->currentIndex();
    QString fileName = model->data(model->index(index.row(), 0)).toString();

    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
        importAct->setText(tr("Import %1").arg(fileName));
        //deleteAct->setText(tr("Delete %1").arg(fileName));
    }

    /* Формируем меню */
    menu.addAction(deleteAct);
    menu.addAction(deleteAllAct);

    menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: As I mentioned treeView->currentIndex() returns a valid ModelIndex every time. indexAt() worked as I needed. Thanks anyway for responding.

Answer (score -1):

The [QTreeWidget::currentItem()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5-snapshot/qtreewidget.html#currentItem) function returns the item that was right-clicked.  It's not clear that it does so based on the description, but based on my usage of it, that is what it does.

Comment: The poster is working with QTreeView, not QTreeWidget. The currentItem method doesn't exist for the "Q...View" classes, only the "Q...List" classes.